# Arduino + 4051 -> noise on certain 4051 pins

Tags: power, arduino-micro, multiplexer

I am trying to use two `4051` ICs with an Arduino Micro right now. The idea was to have an 16-sensor demo station (8 sensors per `4051`) wherein each `4051` pin selection is controlled by a potentiometer as input. I am new to using MUX's, so I mocked the following up as a quick demo based on [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/4051) help document via Arduino (it's basically the same), which only uses one `4051` and does not use a potentiometer as selector input. So, I should be able to set the variable `which` to whatever number (0 - 7) to change the sensor selection that shows up at `A2` on the Arduino.

Setting `which` to 0 is fine, but when I have more than two sensors plugged into `4051` and set the selector pin to any other number than 0 there is a strong likelihood that the output that shows up in the `Serial Monitor` is both unresponsive to the selected sensor change and appears to be simply noise (random numbers around 200 or so). I have been trying to isolate where this noise is coming from and am totally stumped. Has anyone had this issue and, if so, any suggestions on how to further diagnose what is happening? I am currently powering everything off of the Arduino `5V`, which I am under the impression should be okay, though I have tried this with external power supplies (`12V at 2A`, for example) and gotten the same results (so I am fairly certain power is not the issue here).

Measuring voltage on pins 2, 3, and 4, I am seeing 1mV on pin 2, 1mV on pin 3, and 0.9mV on pin 4 following the initial spike during upload. When comparing against the Arduino 4051 doc I linked to above, I see that in that file pins 2, 3, and 4 show a Voltage of 2.5V following the initial spike during upload. Any idea what I am doing incorrectly?

```C++
/*
Sensor Station via MUX

 * code example for useing a 4051 * analog multiplexer / demultiplexer
 * by david c. and tomek n.* for k3 / malmï¿½ hï¿½gskola
 *
 * edited by Ross R.
 */

int r0 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s0)
int r1 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s1)
int r2 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s2)
int which = 0;   //which y pin we are selecting
int val;

void setup() {
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);       // mux1 input
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);    // s0
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);    // s1
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);    // s2
}

void loop () {

  which = (0);

  // select the bit
  r0 = bitRead(which, 0);
  r1 = bitRead(which, 1);
  r2 = bitRead(which, 2);    // use this with arduino 0013 (and newer     versions)

  digitalWrite(2, r0);
  digitalWrite(3, r1);
  digitalWrite(4, r2);

  //Either read or write the multiplexed pin here
  // refactor, this should be digitalWrite with millis or something
  val = analogRead(A2);     // MUX ouputs here

  Serial.print("sensor number ");
  Serial.print(which);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("val is ");
  Serial.println(val);

  delay(2);
}
```

Comment: In the linked code, the `for` loop repeatedly cycles `count` from 0 to 7, so Ard. pins 2-3-4 will average 2.5 V.  In your code, they should sit close to 0 V.  What do you have 4051 pin 6, INH, set at?  What is another value of `which` that you tried, and what was connected to the corresponding 4051 input pin?   Try connecting all of the 4051 input pins (NO0-NO7, pins 13, 1, 15, 2, 14, 5, 12, 4) together and to the sensor or a pot and see if you get the same reading on all 8 channels.

Comment: You don't have a `Serial.begin()` call there so I'm a little surprised you see anything in the serial monitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a post about that chip at [74HC4051 multiplexer / demultiplexer](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=11976).

I made up the circuit shown on my page above with modifications as described below:

[image: 74HC4051 example]

I moved the A/B/C and O/I pins to match your code.

A is the **low-order bit** so pin 11 on the 74HC4051 should go to D2 on the Arduino.

```
74HC4051  Arduino   Meaning
    11       D2        A
    10       D3        B
     9       D4        C
     3       A2        O/I
```

I put a pot on I/O0 (pin 13 on the 74HC4051) and randomly set the other pins to +5 V or Gnd, as shown.

---

In `setup()` I added:

```C++
Serial.begin (115200);
```

I also modified it to automatically sequence through all 8 possible ports, and then stop after 1000 iterations to stop flooding the USB port on my computer. Code is:

```C++
int r0 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s0)
int r1 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s1)
int r2 = 0;      //value of select pin at the 4051 (s2)
int which = 0;   //which y pin we are selecting
int val;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin (115200);
  pinMode(A2, INPUT);       // mux1 input
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);    // s0
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);    // s1
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);    // s2
}  // end of setup

unsigned long counter;

void loop () {

  // select the bit
  r0 = bitRead(which, 0);
  r1 = bitRead(which, 1);
  r2 = bitRead(which, 2);    // use this with arduino 0013 (and newer     versions)

  digitalWrite(2, r0);
  digitalWrite(3, r1);
  digitalWrite(4, r2);

  //Either read or write the multiplexed pin here
  // refactor, this should be digitalWrite with millis or something
  val = analogRead(A2);     // MUX ouputs here

  Serial.print("sensor number ");
  Serial.print(which);
  Serial.print('\t');
  Serial.print("val is ");
  Serial.println(val);

  delay(2);

  if (++which > 7)
    which = 0;

  if (++counter >= 1000)
    {
    Serial.flush ();
    exit (1);
    }   
}  // end of loop
```

---

The output from your sketch was as expected:

```
sensor number 0 val is 781
sensor number 1 val is 0
sensor number 2 val is 1023
sensor number 3 val is 1023
sensor number 4 val is 0
sensor number 5 val is 0
sensor number 6 val is 0
sensor number 7 val is 1023
```

I suggest you check that your wiring agrees with mine.

Comment: Re “I moved the A/B/C and O/I pins to match your code”, your diagram connects 4051 A,B,C to Ard 6,5,4 instead of to Ard 2,3,4.  Also, the code shown in the question doesn't have a loop, so it might be good to include your code in your answer

Comment: @nick, Thanks for your input on this. The omission of `Serial.begin` was an oversight on my part but has been added. Your answer resolved my issue: I had the digital pins connected in the wrong order. Thanks!

Comment: @jwpat7 - I have modified the post to include my test code. `your diagram connects 4051 A,B,C to Ard 6,5,4 instead of to Ard 2,3,4` - true, that was one of my stock schematics. I noted underneath which changes had been made. The code on my linked page matches the schematic. I wanted to use the OP's exact code (as far as possible) in case there were subtle problems with those pins.

Comment: @jwpat7: To make my answer more useful, I redrew the schematic to match the code on this page, to avoid confusion.

Comment: @NickGammon, +1